# How to update SQL if company contains a certain menu

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a database that contains a list of companies. Each Company has access to different things. I need to add a new link for a menu but only for certain companies that have a menulink called ManifestList:

```
SELECT * FROM menu where menulink like '%ManifestList.aspx%' ;
```

This query returns 22 records. So I need to add the new menu for these 22 records only.

My insert statement for adding new records:

```
INSERT INTO `menu` 
(`CompanyID`, 
`MenuName`, 
`MenuLink`, 
`ImageLink`, 
`ListOrder`, 
`Popup`, 
`ParentMenuID`, 
`IsActive`, 
`IsAdmin`) 
SELECT Company_ID, 
'Manifest Analysis', 
'reports/ManifestAnalysisReport.aspx', 
'images/icons/grey/Graph.png', 
'15', 
'0', 
'0', 
'1', 
'0'
FROM companies;
```

But this creates the new menu for all the companies. How do I add this menu only to the records that contain the menulink ManifestList?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you combine both?

```
INSERT INTO `menu` 
(`CompanyID`, 
`MenuName`, 
`MenuLink`, 
`ImageLink`, 
`ListOrder`, 
`Popup`, 
`ParentMenuID`, 
`IsActive`, 
`IsAdmin`) 
SELECT Company_ID, 
'Manifest Analysis', 
'reports/ManifestAnalysisReport.aspx', 
'images/icons/grey/Graph.png', 
'15', 
'0', 
'0', 
'1', 
'0'
FROM companies
WHERE menulink LIKE '%ManifestList.aspx%' ;
```

Comment: I tried that but it causes the error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'menulink' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

I needed to join the menu table to get rid of the error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'menulink' in 'where clause'

I used a left join and I was then able to use menulink

```
FROM companies c
LEFT JOIN menu m on c.Company_ID = m.CompanyID
WHERE m.menulink LIKE '%ManifestList.aspx%' ;
```